# How to preg_match if match found but if not then preg_match another sentence?

Tags: php, preg-match

My $data contains `"<File label=\"cat.{1,20}>(.*?)</File>"` or `"<File label=\"dog.{1,20}>(.*?)</File>"` or `"<File label=\"6969.{1,20}>(.*?)</File>"` how to preg match any of those choices?

`preg_match("'<File label=\"cat.{1,20}>(.*?)</File>'si", $data, $url);` works only for cat. Sorry I am bad to tell what is the problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("'<File label=\"(?:cat|dog|6969).{1,20}>(.*?)</File>'si", $data, $url);
```

this will match all of your $data :)

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)